# criar serviço REST PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, api, rest

Bom dia.

Preciso criar uma API REST em PHP no backend e no frontend mostrar esses dados com angularjs.

backend: API REST em PHP traz dados do banco.

frontend: angular js consome o serviço e disponibiliza no html 5.

Dúvida:

Devo utilizar algum framework de php para construir esse serviço?
É melhor consumir o serviço somente usando javascript ou uso php também?

obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola Amigo existem varias formas de Criar REST com PHP a mais simples delas e usando o Slim Framework.

Veja o post abaixo pra ter uma ideia de como criar um REST.

http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/aprenda-a-usar-o-restful-com-php-e-slim-framework/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Consumir o REST voce pode usar em AngularJS, recomendo voce dar um olhada no link abaixo.

http://rafaell-lycan.com/2015/angular-consumindo-servicos-restful/

Eu trabalho com REST em PHP com Slim e consumindo com AngularJS.

Esta seria uma opção Mais tudo depende do tipo de projeto e do que voce quer fazer.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: é exatamente isso que preciso.. preciso consumir com angular e exibir os dados no browser