# Webservice php sem usar o soap?

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-service, xml

Não tenho familiaridade com Webservice e queria saber como fazer um, sem a necessidade de usar Soap (para pegar dados do banco e consumir no Android Studio).

Comment: Claro que tem! php não é comigo, mas você poderá utilizar a arquitetura REST no seu projeto. aqui nessa resposta tem alguns exemplos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127929/criar-servi%C3%A7o-rest-php

Comment: cara usa json alem de ser fácil qualquer linguagem interpreta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa JSON como retorno...
Aí no Android você recebe com auxílio de alguma biblioteca e cria os objetos usando Gson

Exemplo simples no php que retorna um JSON array:

```
$result = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM usuario");

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $lista[] = $obj;                
        }
    }

    return $lista;
```